# Load and create javascript loop

Tags: php, javascript, sql, yii

I created images slider in clear php and it was worked . but when I changed it under Yii image not loaded because :
- java script block not load image numbers .
- I don't know how I can load javascript block with change variables in yii like php

File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>jquery sliders</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript">var _siteRoot='index.html',_root='index.php';</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="newscript.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <!--/top-->
  <div id="header"><div class="wrap">
   <div id="slide-holder">
<div id="slide-runner">
<?php
            include("samiloxide.php");
//if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");


$section=intval($_GET['section']);

$i=1;
$j=array();

$sql=mysql_query(" select * from images order by section ");



while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  echo    "<a href=''><img id='slide-img-$i' src='$rr[image]' class='slide' alt='' /></a>";
       $j[]=$i;

       $i=$i+1;





        }     
   ?>



    <div id="slide-controls">
     <p id="slide-client" class="text"><strong>post: </strong><span></span></p>
     <p id="slide-desc" class="text"></p>
     <p id="slide-nav"></p>


    </div>
</div>

    <!--content featured gallery here -->
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    if(!window.slider) var slider={

    };
     slider.data=[
    <?php 
  foreach($j as $value){    

echo  "   
  { 'id':'slide-img-$value',
    'client':'First one ',
    'desc':'nature beauty photography'},
   " ;
   }  
   ?>


   ];
   </script>
  </div></div><!--/header-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Just I need to change javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if(!window.slider) var slider={

        };
         slider.data=[
        <?php 
      foreach($j as $value){    

    echo  "   
      { 'id':'slide-img-$value',
        'client':'Some text  ',
        'desc':'image description '},
       " ;
       }  
       ?>


       ];
       </script>
```

To work under Yii  ?

Comment: No errors in  yii but images not disply , also this is not my yii code it's just worked code in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
echo '<a href="#"><img id="slide-img-', $i, '" src="', $rr['image'], '" class="slide" alt="" /></a>';
```

Comment: Alex I had No problem in your code section but my problem in : 
this block will load image in slider mode :
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if(!window.slider) var slider={

    };
     slider.data=[
    <?php 
  foreach($j as $value){    

echo  "   
  { 'id':'slide-img-$value',
    'client':'First one ',
    'desc':'nature beauty photography'},
   " ;
   }  
   ?>


   ];
   </script>

Comment: I'm thinking it could be something to do with an extra comma being in your array. Try using array_map to build the js objects then implode to join them.

Comment: I can generate array  but in load as java script not work ?
I guess i had problem in define javascript with yii

Comment: Yii Forum link :
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/38301-how-to-change-javascript-variables-by-foreach/